# What's the solution to the cross puzzle in the antique shop?

Tags: yesterday

I got to the cross puzzle in the Antique Shop. I realized that I needed to use the wooden box, the crucifix, and the alchemy chart on the large cross in the back room of the antique shop, but once the puzzle actually opened up, I got stuck.

[image]

Not knowing which alchemy symbols to put in each hole, I tried to cancel out of the puzzle to explore more. But I couldn't figure out how to cancel out. I finally decided to hit the "hint" button. It tells me I need to look at the tapestry in the main room. However, since I can't seem to find any way to actually cancel out of the puzzle, I'm left stuck with no in-game way to figure out the solution.

- What's the solution to this puzzle?
- Is there a way to cancel out of the puzzle? I've pressed all the likely keys plus some facerolling of the keyboard, to no avail.

Comment: You should try to click on the 'star' button.  That sometimes lets you go back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try clicking on the 'star' button first and reading the tapestry then solving it yourself, but it is fairly straightforward so you're not really missing out.

The solution is:

> Salt (salis) at the top, mercury (mercurii) on the right, fire (ignis) at the bottom and sulfur on the left.

Comment: The Star button acts kind of like saved game checkpoints. So it does let me back out, in a way, but I have to redo some stuff because it's essentially the same as loading an earlier save. I was hoping for more of just a "cancel" button, but it doesn't appear there is one.

Comment: I think that before you place the pieces you can click on the cross to 'get out' but I don't think that works if you already put the pieces there.  Design flaw, I guess.